# Is it correct to raise custom events from Timer/ BackgroundWorker Completed that go on and update UI

Tags: vb.net, winforms, multithreading, events, invoke

My winforms application needs to interact with hardware devices.
The display is kind of workflow... after step 1 .. completed.. go to step 2 .. etc.
The display is dynamic with controls being made visible at run time and activity being initiated (each of these User controls use timer/ BGWorker within).

I m Raising custom events from timer/ BGWorker_Completed. this will help proceed to the next step and update UI. Am I doing the right thing?

Im a newbie in winforms and Im just not able to figure out why the display is failing.

Im not catching any exception... but after a particular step I do not see the controls !!! I do not know where and how to debug this scenario. If I execute the main form as a stand alone.. I can see the display as well.
however if I navigate from the login page/ change the tabs within the main form and return back.. I do not see the display.

I tried putting in checks before calling the update on UI and in the same order as below.
Thread.Current.IsBackground returns false, control.IsHandleCreated returns true or else Im creating it with dim x=Control.handle())  Me.InvokeRequired/ Control.invokeRequired returns false (the way I wanted). However I do not see userControl being displayed... visibility/color/ everything is being set (in the program).. and Im able to see the hardware interaction!!!.. But no display :-( (step 4 and later)

Im not doing anything fancy in the login page...or in tabChanged events.
(On tab changed event... Im only cleaning up open connections/ closing bg workers if any.. which would be connected back whenever required)

Please let me know if I need to do anything...and how to solve this problem.
I m also calling EnsureHandleIsCreated(control) subroutine soon after initialize component of every user control/ main form.

```
'Code in Login Form
    Dim myForm as new MainForm()
    myForm.ShowDialog(Me) ' here i also tried with show/showDialog.. with/without ownerForm 
    Me.Hide() ' Hide login page

'Code for checking if handle is created or not
    Public Sub CheckForInvalidThread()
        frmMain.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls() = True
        If Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground Or Not Thread.CurrentThread.Name Is THREAD_MAIN_NAME Then
            Throw New InvalidOperationException(THREAD_IS_INVALID)
        End If
        If Not Me.IsHandleCreated Then
            Dim x = Me.Handle()
            Thread.Sleep(20)
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Sub EnsureHandleIsCreated(ByRef c As Control)
        Try
            If Not c.IsHandleCreated Then
                Dim h As System.IntPtr = c.Handle()
            End If
        If c.HasChildren Then
                For Each child As Control In c.Controls
                    Try
                        EnsureHandleIsCreated(child)
                    Catch ex As Exception
                        DAL.LogException(ex.Message, ex.StackTrace, "EnsureHandleIsCreated: " & c.Name, 0)
                    End Try

                Next
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            DAL.LogException(ex.Message, ex.StackTrace, "EnsureHandleIsCreated: " & c.Name, 0)
        End Try
    End Sub 

    Private Sub frmMain_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        lbRole.Text = RoleName
        lbName.Text = UserName
        Try
            Me.Activate()

            If Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground Then
                Throw New ApplicationException(THREAD_IS_INVALID)
            End If
            Thread.CurrentThread.Name = THREAD_MAIN_NAME

            CheckForInvalidThread()
            clGlobals.frmMain = Me

            If RoleName Is Nothing Or String.IsNullOrEmpty(RoleName) Or RoleName.Equals("OPERATOR", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) Then
                tcEtch.TabPages("tbMaintenance").Hide()
                tcEtch.TabPages("tbAdmin").Hide()
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
             MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    Exit Sub
        Finally

        End Try
        Initiate()
    End Sub 

    Public Sub GoToNextStep() Handles Me.GoToNextStepEvent
        Try
           CheckForInvalidThread()
           CurrentStep = CurrentStep + 1

            Select Case CurrentStep
                Case 0 To 2
                    If Me.InvokeRequired Then
                        _delegateDisplayInitiate = AddressOf DisplayStep2
                        Me.Invoke(_delegateDisplayInitiate)
                    Else
                        DisplayStep2()
                    End If

                Case 3
                    If ucCycleStart.InvokeRequired Then
                        _delegateDisplayInitiate = AddressOf DisplayStep3
                        ucCycleStart.Invoke(_delegateDisplayInitiate)
                    Else
                        DisplayStep3()
                    End If
                Case 4
                    If Me.InvokeRequired Or ucPartCountVerification.InvokeRequired Or Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground Then
                        Throw New Exception("Check out")
                    End If

                    EnsureHandleIsCreated(ucPartCountVerification)
                    If ucPartCountVerification.InvokeRequired Then
                        _delegateDisplayInitiate = AddressOf DisplayStep4
                        ucPartCountVerification.Invoke(_delegateDisplayInitiate)
                    Else
                        DisplayStep4()
                    End If

             End Select
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End Try
    End Sub


     Private Sub DisplayStep4() Handles Me.DisplayStep4Event
        ucPartCountVerification.Visible = True
        ucPartCountVerification.Show()
        ucPartCountVerification.Initiate()
    End Sub

     Public Sub Initiate()
            frmMain.CheckForInvalidThread()

            'Just to verify if things are fine.. i put in this check below
        If Me.InvokeRequired Or pnStep4.InvokeRequired Or Not (Me.IsHandleCreated And pnStep4.IsHandleCreated ) Then
                MessageBox.Show("cHECK OUT")
            Else
                Me.Visible = True
                pnStep4.Visible = True

                Me.BackColor = Color.Red
                pnStep4.BackColor = Color.Gray

                Dim height = Me.Size.Height
                Dim width = Me.Size.Width
                MessageBox.Show(height.ToString() + Me.InvokeRequired.ToString())
            End If

    end Sub
```

Comment: That gives me some hope. Thank you. Will be posting in the code tomorrow. Your opinion will surely help me a lot. Thanks P6345uk and thank you Jon.

Comment: Will it be possible to provide your email id? I may be reached at findMadan@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

You certainly can raise events from a `BackgroundWorker` or `Timer`. You're already checking `InvokeRequired`, which is the correct thing to do. You need to then call `BeginInvoke` (or `Invoke`, if it needs to be synchronous) to update your UI.

Comment: That gives me some hope. Thank you. Will be posting in the code tomorrow. Thanks P6345uk and thank you Jon.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track. When dealing with the events that come from some libraries, you cannot be certain on which thread they are delivered. That is disappointing because Windows Forms has the restriction that call calls be made from the GUI thread. [This MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188732.aspx) explains the problem.

You are on the right track with [`InvokeRequired`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired.aspx). It lets you see whether you are on the right thread, but you need a way to handle this case and re-invkoe the event on the proper thread.

Here is how I do this in C#...

```
public delegate void uiEventHandler();

void uiEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (InvokeRequired)
    {
        // We are not on the correct thread. We'd better get there.
        var eh = new uiEventHandler(uiEvent);
        Invoke(eh, new object[] { sender, e });
        return; //This thread has no more work to do.
    }

    // Do your work here that requires being performed on the GUI thread.
}
```